# How to redirect to spesific tab on adminlte using laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I use the LTE Admin template 3.0.1 and Laravel 6.6.2.

Well, I have 3 tabs, Activity, Settings, and change password. 
And the crud in the settings and change passwords has worked. 
but when submitting, for example the form in the settings always redirect to the activity tab not the settings. 
The point is how to when I submit the form in the settings tab, redirect to the settings tab as well. And of course in the password change tab as well.

[Screenshoot of the view/tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ha0WU.png)
And what I have done,

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (window.location.hash == '#settings') {
        $('li.activity').removeClass('active'); //remove active class
        $('div#activity').removeClass('active');
        $('li.settings').addClass('active');
        $('div#settings').addClass('in active');
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="card-header p-2">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills tabtab">
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="activity nav-link active" href="#activity" data-toggle="tab">Activity</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="settings nav-link" href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="changePassword nav-link" href="#changePassword" data-toggle="tab">Change Password</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="active tab-pane" id="activity"> content </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings"> content </div>
  <div class="changePassword tab-pane" id="changePassword"> content </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add the hash to the redirect you are returning

Comment: Assuming you are returning to form by `return redirect()->back()`. Try this,
    `var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
        $('.card-header a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
    }`

Comment: Thanks for helping, but it doesn't work...